# Asteriks wildcard doesn't work in SQL Server full-text search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, prefix

```
Select d.Path 
from Documents d 
inner join (SELECT FT_TBL.DocumentId, KEY_TBL.RANK as ranks
            FROM FullTextCatalog AS FT_TBL 
            INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(FullTextCatalog, Icerik, 
            ' "hısım*" ' ) AS KEY_TBL
            ON FT_TBL.DocumentId = KEY_TBL.[KEY]) as results on d.Id = results.DocumentId 
order by results.ranks
```

This query returns only the rows which have "hısım" word itself. But expected results should have the word "hısım" with its prefixes. am i right? i.e. "hısımlar", "hısımları" etc.

so what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use CONTAINSTABLE instead

```
Select d.Path 
from Documents d 
inner join (SELECT FT_TBL.DocumentId, KEY_TBL.RANK as ranks
        FROM FullTextCatalog AS FT_TBL 
        INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(FullTextCatalog, Icerik, 
        ' "hısım*" ' ) AS KEY_TBL
        ON FT_TBL.DocumentId = KEY_TBL.[KEY]) as results on d.Id = results.DocumentId 
order by results.ranks
```

It works on my example.